# Unable to read the JSON array element data from event based kafka topic message connection in IICS/IDMC

Tags: apache-kafka, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

We are able to view the  kafka topic message as event i/p from Event source connection when it has element with value pair however when an element has an array of data then we are not seeing that data in input field of kafka event in Process Asset that is defined with Kafka consumer event source connection and below is the example

```
`{
 "productInitialLoad": {
"Name": "derivatives",
"type": "abc"
},
"consumerName": ["ABCD"]
}`
```

we are able to view the data in the event input field for above message however for below message we are unable to view consumerName data in input field of event

```
{
 "productInitialLoad": {
"Name":"derivatives",
"type": "abc"
},`
"consumerName": ["ABCD","FHOT"]
}
```

in the above message we  are able to see the event data for Name and Type under productInitialload element however not able to view any data for other element i.e consumerName and the element name also not visible in the input field for event under start task

we want to see the consumerName element data in input field under start task for event message  when it comes in Array form so that we can apply some logic on consumerName data in Assignment task and desicion task to filter based on the values inside the array

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka connection under Event sources,select Simplify content property as No and this will allow the element data appear in event though it repeats the element name data for each array element present